# How can I change the difficulty?

Tags: diablo-iii

Is there a way to change the difficulty back to normal after you've started a game on nightmare?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to change the difficulty level back to normal, you have to go to your Character selection screen, select the quest/act and then use the drop down menu in the bottom left hand corner to change the difficulty (re: screenshot).

[image]

Comment: can you change the difficulty from normal to nightmare, i have unlocked it though

Answer (score 7):

1. Go to your character select screen
2. Select Change Quest
3. Near the bottom you can change difficulty.

**NOTE: Each difficulty has to be unlocked first!**

**Normal** - available by default

**Nightmare** - Beat all 4 acts and be at least level 30

**Hell** - Beat all 4 acts on Nightmare and be at least level 50

**Inferno** - Beat all 4 acts on Hell and be at least level 60

Answer (score 1):

Select "Change Quest" from the Character Menu. At the bottom left of the menu you can change the difficulty.